# Creating Retina-capable programs with Eclipse on MacBook Pro

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, retina-display, screen-resolution

I just downloaded Eclipse on my new MacBook Pro Retina and it looked very terrible.
Then I searched on the Internet and found a little "hack" which let Eclipse look nice on the Retina display. But when I want to run a java project, the whole program looks terrible again.

Is there any "hack" which lets the developed program appear in high resolution?

Comment: What is not appearing correctly? Text or graphics? Also, what Java version are you using?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, you are reliant on the JVMs driver integration/support. As Eclipse uses SWT (as apposed to Swing or AWT), there might be a setting that it can deploy to take advantage of the I creased DPI. Oath wise, you'll need to wait for an update to Java to bring support over for it

Comment: If you don't mind using Java 6, you could take a look at [this](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=215141), read down a bit

Comment: For example this JOptionPane here: http://i50.tinypic.com/347h7cg.png
The Header appears very clearly but the other text is not really nice.
Atm use Java 7, but I'll look at the page you've posted. Thx

Comment: I just changed my project from Java 7 > Java 6 and it works. I think its a bug in java 7. Thx for your help guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, the only way that you can have retina-capable programs that use Swing or AWT is to run Java 6 on the client machine. It doesn't matter what IDE it was compiled in, it just matters what the client is running. This is because Java 6 for Mac was created by Apple and they used some proprietary rendering technology that is not available to Java 7 under the OpenJDK project.

However, a fix [has been submitted](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/macosx-port-dev/2013-April/005491.html) to the Mac OS X OpenJDK port which provides HiDPI (i.e. retina) support for the Aqua Look and Feel in Java 8. There [are plans](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/macosx-port-dev/2013-April/005508.html) to backport this to Java 7 once it is more stable and has been integrated into Java 8.

It should also be noted that Eclipse doesn't look blurry in Java 7 because it uses SWT, rather than AWT or Swing. Basically, it uses a different technology that relies exclusively on Mac OS X to provide its layout content, and it provides an HiDPI image when needed. You could get the same effect if you run SWT instead of Swing or AWT, but you have to turn it into a Cocoa app and modify the Info.plist file for the app (instructions [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/HighResolutionOSX/Explained/Explained.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012302-CH4-SW1) at the bottom).